# DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel

Tags: primefaces, datatable, datamodel

I was using dataTable to display list of Objects (Primefaces 3.0) with no issues. But when I switched to 3.1RC1, I got the error :

DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled

There are two solutions for this problem:

1. Adding rowKey, selection and selectionMode attributes to dataTable
2. Implementing SelectableDataModel interface and extending a DataModel like ListDataModel for filling the dataTable

I am not able to decide which is the perfect solution. First solution looks simpler as it requires less code changes.
But, I am not sure whether it is ideal solution. Request you to help me out in deciding on this. Thank you.

Comment: For now, I just added rowKey to resolve the issue, as this requires very little change to my existing sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add rowKey to resolve the issue as this requires very little change to existing sources